# Enum.Parse & Custom Separators

Tags: .net, enums

Currently, `Enum.Parse` supports only the comma as the value separator, so that

```
MemberOne,MemberThree
```

will be correctly parsed but

```
MemberOne|MemberThree
```

won't. Is there any way to force `Enum.Parse` to accept other characters as the separator (for example, the '`|`') without using `String.Replace` on the `expression` parameter?

Comment: What are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Nothing, actually... It's just that it is more logical to use '|' instead of ',' when `Enum.Parse` actually uses bitwise `OR` when multiple values are specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add your own custom helper method for the Enum class like this:

```
public static class EnumHelpers
{
    public static object Parse(Type enumType, string value, char separator)
    {
        return Enum.Parse(enumType, value.Replace(separator, ','));
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
myEnum x = (myEnum)EnumHelpers.Parse(typeof(myEnum), "a|b", '|');
```

I'm not really sure if this meets your criteria - it's still using string.Replace, but you don't have to use it in the parameter.

You could also have a method like this which could accept multiple options without specifying the separator on each call:

```
private const char[] additionalSeparators = new char[] { '|', '$', '#' };

public static object Parse(Type enumType, string input)
{
    string val = input;
    foreach(char c in additionalSeparators)
    {
        val = val.Replace(c, ',');
    }
    return Enum.Parse(enumType, val);
}
```

which could be called like this:

```
myEnum x = (myEnum)EnumHelpers.Parse(typeof(myEnum), "a|b");
```

Comment: +1 - You beat me to the answer. The separator char in the Enum.Parse/TryParse is hardcoded as a ',' in the framework, so extension this method is the simplest way.